# Access Can't delete records due to lock violations

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

We have been using a Delete command on Access 2003 with xp machine from past few years and it was working good until we upgraded our systems to Access 2010 and Windows 7.

Please see the error below. No sure what i was missing. I tried creating a new link oracle table, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you still have a unique key? Sometimes you have to assign them when you link the table.

Comment: It still runs good with Access 2007 on XP machine.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same lock error when trying to update a linked SQL Server table via MS Access 2010.

This may no longer be a problem for you since the thread is so old, but hopefully it makes it easier on someone else in the future.

**I was able to fix it by changing the ID field in SQL Server from a bigint to an int.**

You may also want to make sure that "Default record locking" is set to "No locks" in Access Options --> Client Settings --> Advanced
[DefaultRecordLocking http://www.tmetrics.net/support/patrick/stackoverflow/defaultrecordlocking.jpg](http://www.tmetrics.net/support/patrick/stackoverflow/defaultrecordlocking.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I had this error with a linked table that had a primary key and a unique key. When linking the table, Access assumed the unique key was the primary key.

By temporarily disabling or deleting the unique key and refreshing the ling using Linked Table Manager" the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the 332 records it can't delete are locked, perhaps by some other process?  Is there a stagnant process running somewhere that is holding a lock on those records?

Comment: No stagnant process running. when i use the same file with Access 2007 on XP, it deletes all the records at once.

Comment: Start listing out the differences between the machines.  You've already noted the operating system and versions of Access, so keep going.  It doesn't seem like those two differences would cause what you are experiencing, so perhaps there is some other difference that is causing this.

Comment: @NickDeVore...No other differences exists.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem... Could delete records manually, but through query was getting that message.

Even though I was deleting records in the "many" table in a one-to-many relationship, a "key violation" message kept appearing.

I edited the relationship to ADD **Cascade Update** and **Cascade Delete**, and the problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

I am having this problem.  I have an Access front-end to an Oracle database.  I am trying to delete records from a linked table.  I have not found a solution anywhere on the internet.  Here is my "solution".
I converted from DoCmd.RunSQL to DBS.Execute to run my Delete query.  That got rid of the error message.  But not all records were being deleted still.  So now I execute the delete query in a loop.
    recCount = DLookup("count(*)", "my_table")

```
Do While recCount > 0       
    DBS.Execute "DELETE * FROM my_table", dbSeeChanges 
    recCount = DLookup("count(*)", "prod_nmpsia_premiums")
Loop
```

Sometimes it only takes one pass.  Other times it takes a few.
I know it's a kludge.  But it works.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this same issue using Access 2016 and an Oracle database.  I could append to the Oracle tables just fine, but when I ran the delete query to remove those same records, it would delete some records and say others were locked.  If I looped the query enough times it would eventually erase all the records.

The solution I found was in the Access delete query, I set the 'Use Transactions' property to 'No' and it started working fine without any record locks.  I don't know if this is a perfect solution, but it is working in my case.

--Update--

The above solution worked for some of my queries but then I still ran into the issue on other queries.  So it helped in some cases but didn't work completely.

What does seem to be working now is that I stored a Procedure in Oracle that would delete the data I needed to delete and I am calling that procedure from Access.